Is adding enum value to public API a semver patch, minor, or major change?
If I have an API that returns an enum as part of its payload, and I make an update that adds a new value. What part of the SemVer should I update for the API?
For example:

Before
enum = A: 1, B: 2

Possible API output:
{
"value": 2
}


After
enum = A: 1, B: 2, C: 3

Possible API output:
{
"value": 3
}



I see different arguments:

Arguments for Major [x+1.y.z]

An enum indicates a set list of allowed values. Any value outside of that is an error, thus changing the list changes the whole assumption model.
If consumers implement the code for each enum value, it could break if a new value enters.


Arguments for Minor [x.y+1.z]

A new enum value can be seen as an addition, such as adding a new field.
Enums are usually implemented as a switch/match statement, so usually there is a default action for unseen values.


Arguments for Patch [x.y.z+1]
(I don't particularly agree that patch is a good choice, but here are some arguments)

Enum is a number, and any number should be expected, and thus it is not even an addition.



